# Name curves in plots

Tags: plotting

I'm a beginner in Mathematica. The following gives me two intersecting curves as a small result of my research. I'd like to name the blue curve $\theta_0$ and the orange curve $\theta_1$ in the plot. How can I do that?

```
ListLinePlot[{{{0.01, 0.03471264171264647}, {0.02, 
    0.07347515730438557}, {0.03, 0.11369872249887712}, {0.04, 
    0.15545878269727856}, {0.05, 0.1988391022269042}, {0.06, 
    0.2439325115466433}, {0.07, 0.29084173265874697}, {0.08, 
    0.33968029314041465}, {0.09, 0.3905735405486506}, {0.1, 
    0.4436597705326078}}, {{0.01, 0.0400026678413429}, {0.02, 
    0.08002133516148463}, {0.03, 0.1200720130205868}, {0.04, 
    0.16017072164262638}, {0.05, 0.20033349990845323}, {0.06, 
    0.24057641395973942}, {0.07, 0.2809155634367445}, {0.08, 
    0.32136708202838454}, {0.09, 0.3619471517021425}, {0.1, 
    0.4026720050829319}}}, AxesLabel -> {t, \[theta]}]
```

Thanks in advance for any help or hint!

Comment: try the option [`PlotLabels`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLabels.html)

Answer (score 5):

> I'd like to name the blue curve θ0 and the orange curve θ1 in the
> plot.

You could use `Callout`

```
lis1 = {{0.01, 0.03471264171264647}, {0.02, 
    0.07347515730438557}, {0.03, 0.11369872249887712}, {0.04, 
    0.15545878269727856}, {0.05, 0.1988391022269042}, {0.06, 
    0.2439325115466433}, {0.07, 0.29084173265874697}, {0.08, 
    0.33968029314041465}, {0.09, 0.3905735405486506}, {0.1, 
    0.4436597705326078}};
lis2 = {{0.01, 0.0400026678413429}, {0.02, 
    0.08002133516148463}, {0.03, 0.1200720130205868}, {0.04, 
    0.16017072164262638}, {0.05, 0.20033349990845323}, {0.06, 
    0.24057641395973942}, {0.07, 0.2809155634367445}, {0.08, 
    0.32136708202838454}, {0.09, 0.3619471517021425}, {0.1, 
    0.4026720050829319}};

ListLinePlot[{Callout[lis1, "curve \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(θ\), \(0\)]\)"], 
  Callout[lis2, "curve \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(θ\), \(1\)]\)"]}, 
 AxesLabel -> {t, θ}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

See options in help how to adjust labels if needed.

Another option as mentioned in comment above by kglr is to use `PlotLabels` which gives same output.

```
ListLinePlot[{lis1, lis2}, AxesLabel -> {t, θ}, 
 PlotLabels -> {"curve \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(θ\), \(0\)]\)", 
   "curve \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(θ\), \(1\)]\)"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It looks like Callout and PlotLabels share same code internally since output is same.

> How can I name the whole plot?

You can use `PlotLabel` for that.

```
ListLinePlot[{Callout[lis1, "curve \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(θ\), \(0\)]\)"], 
  Callout[lis2, "curve \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(θ\), \(1\)]\)"]}, 
 AxesLabel -> {t, θ}, 
 PlotLabel -> Style[Text["My nice plot"], Bold, 18]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks! May I ask another question: How can I name the whole plot?

Comment: @IntegralLover fyi, updated.